# Custom error handling vba

Tags: vba

I have a cell that is a brutal nested if and if error. I don't want to have to paste my vlookup 5 times in the formula. Instead, I'd like to have a macro check the errors. The special case is 0 or 1.

I wrote this function to get the value of the vlookup.

```
Public Function ValidateRealization(value As String)
Dim validate As String
If value = "#N/A" Or value = "#VALUE!" Or value or = "#REF!" Or value = "#DIV/0!" Or value = "#NUM!" Or value = "#NAME?" Or value = "#NULL!" Or value = "0" Or value = "1" Then
    validate = ""
Else
    validate = value 
End If


ValidateRealization = validate
End Function
```

However, I know it can be improved for one when I set the value, the formatting as a percentage is overridden.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe by getting the active cells range, and setting the value property?

Comment: What is `ervalue`?

Comment: Oop, my mistake. All the `values` used to be `error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 points: first, you have `ervalue` which is undefined.  Go to the top of your module, and add the line `Option Explicit`.  Then go "Tools" > "Options..." and tick "Require Variable Declaration".

Secondly: Why not accept a `Variant` instead of a `String`, and use `IsError`?

```vb
Public Function ValidateRealization(value As Variant) As Variant
    If IsError(value) Or CStr(value) = "0" Or CStr(value) = "1" Then
        ValidateRealization = ""
    Else
        ValidateRealization = value
    End If
End Function
```

**{EDIT}** *If you have converted your value to a String before passing it, then use [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)*

```vb
Public Function ValidateRealization(value As Variant) As Variant
    If IsError(value) Then
        ValidateRealization = ""
    Else
        Select Case CStr(value)
            Case "#N/A", "#VALUE!", "#REF!", "#DIV/0!", "#NUM!", "#NAME?", "#NULL!", "0", "1"
                ValidateRealization = ""
            Case Else
                ValidateRealization = value
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I have not converted it to a string.  It would seem if I would, then I loose my formatting options (it's a percentage now).

Comment: Converting the errors to strings seemingly work best.  Not sure why, but `IsError` is not catching the error at the `IF`.  For that you get the vote.

Comment: I've just been through and tested all of the errors, and `IfError` recognised them all from `Range.Value` - it may be an issue with what you are passing to the Function?

Answer (score 3):

You are bringing in a string and not a value, so the return is a string.

set the parameter as variant and test for error:

```
Public Function ValidateRealization(value) As Variant
Dim validate As Variant

If Not IsError(value) Then
    If value = 0 Or value = 1 Then
        validate = ""
    Else
        validate = value
    End If
Else
    validate = ""
End If


ValidateRealization = validate
End Function
```

---

Which can be simplified to:

```
Public Function ValidateRealization(value) As Variant
ValidateRealization = ""
 If Not IsError(value) Then
    If Not (value = 0 Or value = 1) Then
        ValidateRealization = value
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: @dwirony No, [`IsError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/iserror-function) will accept a Variant.

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes sorry but my point is it looks like he was bringing in `value` as a string before. He'll need to make sure the argument is a range or a string of `#N/A` won't return True?

Comment: Ah - yes, OP was, but that's why Scott's removed the `As String` from the argument definition.

Comment: @Chronocidal Oops okay I've got it now... I messed up in my own testing.

Comment: Both these answers are great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, for some reason DIV/0 is not caught by this.  Value reads "value = Error 2007", but fails at that if statement.  It's weird.

Comment: @user1093111 sorry went into meeting.  forgot that the IF will try all parts and you cannot equate an error to a number.  see edit.